# JS вращение квадрата

Tags: javascript, библиотеки

Нужно сделать [PageTransitions](https://github.com/codrops/PageTransitions) только который работает как куб. Т.е. 6 сторон, по каждой из которых можно обойти объект. В демо уже есть свойство Rotate -> Cube. Но данное свойств перебирает не как куба, а как цикл страниц, т.е. нет управляемости.

Аналогов в интернете не нашел, как и более детальный гайд чем официальный.

Задача выглядела просто, но просидев ночь со знакомым программистом, мы смогли только [подпортить работу скрипта](http://stekolschikov.tk/demo/2/%D0%A2%D0%972/1/).

Comment: Из вопроса понятно, что в вашей вселенной у квадрата 6 сторон. Траслируйте пожалуйста свой вопрос в наш бренный, трёхмерный мир и создайте jsfiddle/jsbin - обязательно попробуем вам помочь.

Comment: ))) Извините, после сна вселенная уже стала 3Д, исправил.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, в вопросе имелся в виду куб, а не квадрат, но и в этом случае проблем возникнуть не должно.
На первой же странице гугла по запросу [cube page transition](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=cube%20page%20transition) есть несколько реализаций данного вопроса и несколько ссылок на stackoverflow, где люди уже задавали подобные вопросы:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551710/implementing-3d-page-transition-cube-for-different-pages
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384687/css-3-cube-flip-transforms-on-page-transition-using-twitter-bootstrap
3. http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Animated-3D-Cube-Slider-with-jQuery-CSS3.html

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1.5s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.face {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/* Styles the back of the card */

.back {
  color: rgb(34, 65, 108);
  background-color: rgba(78, 150, 249, 1);
  /* Ensure the "back side" is flipped already */
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front {
  background-color: #a00;
}

.right {
  color: rgb(34, 65, 108);
  background-color: rgba(249, 150, 78, 1);
  /* Ensure the "back side" is flipped already */
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
}

#container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  -o-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

#card {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

#card div.face {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#card .front {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(150px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(150px);
  -o-transform: translateZ(150px);
  transform: translateZ(150px);
}

#card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(150px);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(150px);
  -o-transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(150px);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(150px);
}

#card .right {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(150px);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(150px);
  -o-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(150px);
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(150px);
}

#card.show-front {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(-100px);
  -o-transform: translateZ(-100px);
  transform: translateZ(-100px);
}

#card.show-back {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(-180deg);
  -o-transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(-180deg);
  transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(-180deg);
}

#card.show-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(-90deg);
  -o-transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(-90deg);
  transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    var card = $('#card').click(function flip(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (card.hasClass('show-front'))
        card.removeClass('show-front').addClass('show-right');
      else if (card.hasClass('show-right'))
        card.removeClass('show-right').addClass('show-back');
      else if (card.hasClass('show-back'))
        card.removeClass('show-back').addClass('show-front');
    });
  });
</script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="card" class="card show-front">
    <div id="front" class="front face">
      <!--FRONT PAGE START ----------->
      <div>
        <div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="span8">
              <h1>FRONT PAGE</h1>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--FRONT PAGE END----------->
    </div>

    <div id="right" class="right face">
      <!--RIGHT PAGE START ----------->
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="brand" href="/">RIGHT PAGE</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse ">
              <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="/">SUB MENU</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--RIGHT PAGE END ----------->
    </div>
    <div id="back" class="back face">
      <!--BACK PAGE START ----------->
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="brand" href="/">BACK PAGE</a>
            <div class="nav-collapse">
              <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="/">SUB MENU 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/">SUB MENU 2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--BACK PAGE END ----------->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rt4eR/11/

Comment: Да, действительно, есть несколько реализаций. Но в них происходит управление перебором последовательности страниц. 1 потом 2 и т.д.  В моем же задании куб управляем. Спасибо Вам за развернутый ответ. Извините за квадрат )))

Comment: Да, уже готового на 100% решения здесь никто не даст.

Comment: Дмитрий, значит я дам [ссылка](http://stekolschikov.tk/tz/17092015/)

Comment: Если уж решили давать ссылку, то оформите это как следует, в видео ответа к этому вопросу с примером кода.